# Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR issue

Tags: java, android, xml, appcompatactivity

I'm trying to build my app but without success.. I tried several way but nothing was worked. The exception is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
```

My style.xml is:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

        <!-- theme customizations -->

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>

        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/ldrawer_color</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/ldrawer_color</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/ldrawer_color</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

and as you can see i have declared

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
```

This is my manifest.xml

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        tools:replace="android:icon"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

and my `BaseActivity` that i use to extend other activities

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getLayoutResource());
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(BaseActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
            //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    protected abstract int getLayoutResource();

    protected void setActionBarIcon(int iconRes) {
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(iconRes);
    }

}
```

I don't know why it crashes..The only way to start the application without crash is set the parent on the style.xml in `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` but in this way the status bar is transparent and not colored...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Using `Theme.AppCompat.Light` tells Android that you want the framework to provide an ActionBar for you. However, you are creating your own ActionBar (a `Toolbar`), so you are giving the framework mixed signals as to where you want the ActionBar to come from.

Since you are using a Toolbar, you want `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`.

The next step is to make sure your Toolbar is styled correctly, which seems to be where you are running into issues. To style your Toolbar like an ActionBar using the colors you defined for your theme, you need to provide a theme like so:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />
```

See the "styling" section for the Toolbar widget on [this Android Developers blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) for more information.

Comment: Ok seems it's working..i think the problem was the app:theme of the toolbar. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you got this lines in `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Add these extra lines after:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Then add this to your activity in manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".activity.YourActivity"
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"><!-- ADD THIS LINE -->
```

That was best solution for me after checking tutorials and other solutions

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I created a new activity and forgot to define it's app:theme in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".HistoryActivity"
        android:label="History"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Primary"></activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem after changing the value for the "android:theme" for the Activity in the manifest from "@style/AppTheme" to "@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar":

```
<activity android:name=".MyXXXActivity"
            ...                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

 <android.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

 </android.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
 <activity android:name=".activity.activity_name"
           android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
 </activity>
```

Comment: Please explain your solution instead of just giving code

Comment: first of all you have to write this code which is below in the values/style.    
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>                                                                                                          
 After that write this into your main_activity..<android.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></android.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
in the last you just need to write last  code into your manifest.xml: