# Cannot build SlideUpPanel demo on android

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am trying to rebuild the sample of this library:

https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

using Android Studio 1.5, however when it gets to "setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar));" it throws an exception.

```
public class DemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "DemoActivity";
private SlidingUpPanelLayout mLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);

    setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar));
```

exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.sothree.slidinguppanel/com.sothree.slidinguppanel.demo.
DemoActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor.
Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to
false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
```

my styles.xml

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#ffff9431</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#ffD56600</item>
```

I have windowActionBar set to false. I even tried to remove it, but it does not work.

I tried this thread but no success:

[This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515058/this-activity-already-has-an-action-bar-supplied-by-the-window-decor)

any idea what is going on?

Comment: nevermind, this thread shows the proper fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923403/do-not-request-window-feature-action-bar-issue

Comment: if u use toolbar than use Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar in your style

<style name="NoActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
     ...
</style>