# This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor Error on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to launch a new `Activity` from my main one. Every time I execute it I get,

```
Unfortunately, My application has Stopped.
```

I´ve been going through similar questions but still can't solve my problem.

**Here's the `Manifest`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.usuario.myapplication">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".secondActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

**Java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView texto;
    EditText editText;
    Button boton;
    Button boton2;

    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case (R.id.boton):
                String dato = editText.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), dato, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                texto.setText(dato);
                break;
            case (R.id.boton2):
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

        texto = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto);
        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        boton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.boton);
        boton2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.boton2);
        boton.setOnClickListener(this);
        boton2.setOnClickListener(this);



    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.usuario.myapplication/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.usuario.myapplication/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

**XML:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.usuario.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="ingresar dato" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/boton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/boton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/boton2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="new activity" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**And here is the `Logcat`:**

```
01-24 14:27:42.042 8033-8033/com.example.usuario.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.usuario.myapplication, PID: 8033
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.usuario.myapplication/com.example.usuario.myapplication.secondActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:198)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:99)
                      at com.example.usuario.myapplication.secondActivity.onCreate(secondActivity.java:17)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**Second Activity:**

```
package com.example.usuario.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

public class secondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: please post the logcat as well as code for SecondActivity.

Comment: Could you please at least read the exception that you got? Let me guess - you are using method requestWindowFeature or supportRequestWindowFeature in your second activity - am I right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do not request Window.FEATURE\_ACTION\_BAR issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923403/do-not-request-window-feature-action-bar-issue)

Answer (score 3):

As per logcat log; there is a confliction between implementation of `Manifest` file and `SecondActivity` class.

You got two solutions here but implement either of them :

> 1. You can remove the complete two line "Toolbar" implementation code.
> 2. You may make this change in manifest file as below :
>
>    ```
>             android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
>    ```

Hope it would help you out.

Cheers!

Comment: @LinX64 : Thanks for correction. Monstruone - While re-correcting your code I'd suggest you to consider mine suggestion along with LinX64 considerations too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this from your `Manifest` file:

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<activity
        android:name=".secondActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

To:

```
<activity
    android:name=".secondActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask" />
```

Comment: Please provide me a LogCat.

Answer (score 0):

In your AppTheme style use,

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar
```

instead of

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar
```

You are setting a theme that has an actionbar and then you are setting toolbar as an actionbar. That's why your are getting this error.

**Use the theme that has no actionbar instead and it will fix the issue.**

Answer (score 0):

**Since you already have a `Toolbar` Use this (In your `Styles`):**

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar
```

**Example:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

And also, add these two:

```
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

**According to:**

> This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor.
>   Do not request `Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR` and set
>   `windowActionBar` to false in your theme to use a `Toolbar` instead.

Perhaps you wanna try this also in your `OnCreate`:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case (R.id.boton):
                String dato = editText.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), dato, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                texto.setText(dato);
                break;
            case (R.id.boton2):
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    The problem is in your Manifest file.
```

Change the following portion of your Manifest xml file from this;
    `enter code here`

```
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".secondActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>'
```

to this;

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".secondActivity"
<!--Add the following line to each of your activities in the manifest-->
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
</activity>'
```