# Android Developer Tool Bar Error

Tags: android, performance, material-design, android-5.0-lollipop, android-toolbar

I'm getting this error when running 'My First App' from Android Developer tutorial:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action
>   bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request
>   Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in
>   your theme to use a Toolbar instead

My Activity Display Message.mxl looks like this:

> ```
> <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
>
>     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
>         android:id="@+id/toolbar"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
>         android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
>         app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
>
> </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
>
> <include layout="@layout/content_display_message" />
>
> <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
>     android:id="@+id/fab"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
>     android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
>     android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
> ```

How do I solve this error?
I would assume that I would need to insert code like

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

somewhere here? 
I can include my java code if it will help, but I'm sure there error is in the display message xml

Comment: Can you please post a code snippet from your activity's `onCreate()` function?

Comment: I think this is the answer of your question  http://stackoverflow.com/a/30923502/3145960