# I wanted to start LoginActivity then enter to Navigation Drawer Activity (MainActivity) but always error?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

This is my Login Activity, I got one button to enter MainActivity which is contain Navigation Drawer already

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I already change the AndroidManifest to make LoginActivity as default start activity, but when I click the button, it wont enter the MainActivity.

This is the error

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.breakthrough.myapplication22, PID: 11422
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.breakthrough.myapplication22/com.breakthrough.myapplication22.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action
>   bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request
>   Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in
>   your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do
>   not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar
>   to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:199)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:133)
>                         at com.breakthrough.myapplication22.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: If you would do an internet search with the message from the exception you would get an answer before you ask the question here ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do not request Window.FEATURE\_ACTION\_BAR issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923403/do-not-request-window-feature-action-bar-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Remove those 2 lines:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear enough, your code failed at MainActivity.java line 24.

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

because your MainActivity is already has default ActionBar. To solve this problem go to your styles.xml and change your baseTheme from

```
parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```